# Imported jar files creates empty packages

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ibm-mq

I am importing a Jar file "com.ibm.mq.jar" into my workspace(Eclipse IDE).
While importing, a screen came where I could see all the classes in the Jar file.

After I imported it into the work space, I was able to import the package and following statement didn't give any error.

```
  import com.ibm.mq.*;
```

But, in code I am not able to use any of the classes which were there in the package.
Like, "MQC" is a class in the package, but in code it doesn't reflect("MQC cannot be resolved as a type" error comes if I try to use it).

This jar file actually contains Websphere MQ API classes.

Can anyone advise, what am I missing.

Comment: Add the jar to the Java Build Path preference windows and then reorganize imports (ctrl + shift + o). Importing is not as adding the jar to project classpath IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MQ 7, check its documentation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/index.html). There was some stuff going on about deprecation of `com.ibm.mq.mqc` and, depending on the version you use, that class was replaced by `com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants`. Like this one, there are other cases.

In fact `com.ibm.mq` only contains the exception `MQException`, so you won't find any classes there. I suggest you check the version you're using and dig a little deeper into the docs, as a first step.